# Using cin.ignore AFTER cin.get to ignore extra inputs

Tags: c++

The user is prompted to "enter a middle initial".  What happens if they enter a space, full name, or maybe a letter followed by a period '.' ?
How can we modify the program to handle this using cin.ignore?
This is the code I currently have:
I commented out the area I'm having trouble with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string fname, lname;
    char MI;
    cout << "Please enter your first name: ";
    cin >> fname;                                           
    cout << "Please enter your middle initial: ";
    cin.ignore(1, '\n');                                    
    cin.get(MI);                                        
    cout << "Please enter your last name: ";
      //cin.ignore('\n')
    cin >> lname;
    cout << "Your name is " << fname << " " << MI << " " << lname << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I have this other cin.ignore in it still doesn't do anything and the last name reads the extra inputs.  I've tried adding a number of characters to read and it still doesn't fix the problem.  When I run it it just skips the input for last name.  I also tried changing the last name input to getline but if still didn't do anything.

Comment: probably easier just to use `std::getline` then check the resulting string

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `std::getline` and `std::istringstream`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string fname, lname;
    std::string MI;

    std::cout << "Please enter your first name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, fname);
    std::istringstream iss(fname);
    iss >> fname;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter your middle initial: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, MI);

    } while (MI.size() != 1);

    std::cout << "Please enter your last name: ";

    std::cin >> lname;
    std::cout << "Your name is " << fname << " " << MI << " " << lname << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here for `fname` I have used `std::getline` to get user input and then I've used `std::istringstream` to get only one word of the input.

For `MI` I have made it a string and until and unless the user doesn't provide a single character, the program doesn't continue.

And the `lname` part is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

```
cin.ignore(1, '\n');                                    
cin.get(MI);
```

To simply:

```
cin >> MI;
```

Let `operator>>` ignore any white space, including line breaks, between the first name and the middle initial.

After reading `MI`, you can then use the following to ignore everything up to the next input:

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string fname, lname;
    char MI;
    cout << "Please enter your first name: ";
    cin >> fname;
    cout << "Please enter your middle initial: ";
    cin >> MI;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << "Please enter your last name: ";
    cin >> lname;
    cout << "Your name is " << fname << " " << MI << " " << lname << endl;
    return 0;
}
```